# interceptor in angular and module federation

Tags: angular, micro-frontend

I use angular with module-federation to build microfrontend app. I have a shell-project and a remote-project that working together with module federation. I have one HTTP_INTERCEPTORS in the shell-project and another HTTP_INTERCEPTORS in the remote-project.
problem is that when I call http request in the remote-project the request intercepts only from shell project and remote-project interceptor is skipping. I have tried decorators @SkipSelf and @Self but they are not my desired. because I don't want skip not self injector and nor parent host injector. I want just intercept my http-request by two HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, I mean interceptor that is in shell-project and interceptor that is in the remote-project.
I don't know how do that.

Comment: Hey I'm in the same case did you find any solution to your issue ?

Comment: Actually No, At the end we decided to duplicate interceptor in the micro-app. Of course we tested a way putting interceptor in a library and install that library in shell and micro-apps that was working but finally we didn't use that way and we did duplication of interceptors.

Comment: Yeah but how did make the interceptor in microfrontend remote to work I couldn't do that since it was lazy loaded the interceptor of my microapp didn't launch only the one in the shell, and I have the same interceptor in shell and remote

Comment: Well, in the remote project go to yourService and remove {providedIn: 'root'} after removing that, yourService decorator should be like the @Injectable().

after doing this go to your module which uses yourService and add YourService to the providers array. Now request that are in the yourService should pass from shell interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `HttpClient` cannot see microfrontend `interceptor` since it is provided before `HTTP_INTERCEPTOR` is provided. You should create new `HttpClient` that has child `interceptors`, you can follow this [article](https://indepth.dev/posts/1455/how-to-split-http-interceptors-between-multiple-backends)